# Cordova good performance transitions

Tags: android, cordova

I am making a Cordova App. Like in almost all Apps you can switch between different pages. I maked an jQuery animation where the new page comes from the left to the right:

```
$('#seite_2').css('left', '-100%');    
$('#seite_2').animate({left: '0%'}, 150);
```

I am having a Galaxy S6 and the animation is very laggy.
So which animation should I use to have a good (without a lag) animation.
I dont have to come from the left to the right. It also can be a different type of animation, which looks better than a direct page swap.
An other CSS animation or an Plugin would be very cool ;)

Comment: The best way is NOT to use multiple HTML files, just make a single page app. Every file load will slow down your app and it is much more complicate to develop a multi page app. docs: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/next/index.html

Comment: Yes its all in one HTML file but there are different page divs. And the problem is that the animation of them is very slow, wehne they are "flying" in.

Comment: Could you share your full code on https://jsfiddle.net/ or other site? I think it could be effected by other component, not JQuery library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be overkill for a mobile app, but in general [velocity.js](http://velocityjs.org) delivers high performance animations. On their website you can also read why jQuery and CSS animations are slower:

> **Secret Sauce**
>
> JavaScript and jQuery are falsely conflated. JavaScript
>   animation, which Velocity uses, is fast; it's jQuery that's slow.
>   Although Velocity works alongside jQuery, it uses its own animation
>   stack that delivers its performance through two underlying principles:
>   1) synchronize the DOM → tween stack to minimize layout thrashing, and
>   2) cache values to minimize DOM querying.

**Update:** If you prefer CSS3 Animations, there are a few rules to follow to achieve 60FPS performance: https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108

Answer (score 0):

Hardware acceleration CSS usually improves this kind of transitions. With this CSS lanes:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
   -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
   -o-transform: translateZ(0);
   transform: translateZ(0);
```

triggers GPU acceleration in modern desktop and mobile browsers. This seems to be the most effective way of triggering GPU acceleration (all vendor prefixes included)

Link for more info: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css Or just google for "hardware acceleration CSS"

Comment: Why do i have to use this all -webkit- ,-moz- ,-ms- ,... it also works with just translate. Is that only for older browser?

Comment: yes, with transform or -webkit-transform should work, its also added just in case that you want to migrate to web and support major browsers

Comment: so i dont hava to use it when i am usign a moidern browser?

Comment: Can you give a code, like mine, where an whole page div comes from the left with hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using **AngularJS**? I tried Jquery animations for page transitions for a long time before try AngularJS animations. They are smooth and quick and you can personalize your own interactions.

You just need to create a CSS style and include it to your Single Page Application main Div. Look:

**HTML**

```
<script src="angular/angular-animate.js"></script> 
..
<div id="mainMainDiv" class="fadeExample" ng-view=""></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fadeExample{
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}
.fadeExample.ng-enter,
.fadeExample.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.fadeExample.ng-enter {
    opacity: 0;
}
.fadeExample.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
.fadeExample-leave {
    opacity: 1;
}
.fadeExample.ng-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**Sources:**

[About the ngAnimate, ngLeave and ngEnter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate)

[Other Example](http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-switch/slider-css3-transition-animation)

Hope it helps! Best regards!